# Calling WebService Without adding web reference in c#.net framework 2.0 for windows phone 7

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7

I am developing backoffice application for windows phone 7.1 minimum req. It consumes asmx webservice for that. But I want to make application such a way that it can connect to any client's server. So i need to change webservice path each time keeping methods same as over. Is there any way to call websevice directly in windows phone 7 without adding web reference??

Sample Code :

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"" + Namespace + methodName + "\"");
req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
req.Accept = "text/xml";
req.Method = "POST";
using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
{
string postValues = "";

if (Convert.ToInt32(Params["number"]) > 0)
{
foreach (var param in Params)
{
    if (encode) postValues += string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param.Key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param.Value));
    else postValues += string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", param.Key, param.Value);
}
}
soapStr = string.Format(soapStr, methodName, postValues);
using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
{
    stmw.Write(soapStr);
}
}

using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
string result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
//ResponseSOAP = XDocument.Parse(Utils.UnescapeString(result));
ExtractResult(methodName);
}
```

Errors :

1. 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting
   a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetRequestStream' and no extension method 'GetRequestStream' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You can achieve this by using HTTP requests which requires a url... I wouldn't suggest this though(you have to make sure the asmx service is http get and post enabled.) i would rather suggest making a collection of the services he already has..

Comment: @Jonny I have developed one class, by which i can call webservice without adding web reference, bt as windows phone 7 use .net framework 2.0 it gives me some error.  Check the following link

http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/calling-a-web-method-in-c-without-a-service-reference/

Comment: @sumit_dev Can you post the error that you get? And i can possibly help. I'm going on the basis that your class is identical to the code in the link.

Comment: @Jonny I have update my code and error. As i am developing in Silverlight Windows Phone 7 app, I am not getting System.Net.WebHeaderCollection & System.Net.HttpWebRequest assemblies

Comment: @sumit_dev try using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.2.28

Comment: @sumit_dev  any advance with this problem?

Comment: @DiomedesDominguez Still stuck on same issue. I was followed the steps which you are given but still errors are same.. I am trying to make this application compactible with silverlight windows phone OS 7.1 and this sdk supports .net framework version 2.0, this is what the big issue for me...

Comment: @DiomedesDominguez 

i have got the solution finally. Thanks for Your support.

Comment: @Jonny

i have got the solution finally. Thanks for Your support.

Comment: @SumitDev Please post your solution and mark it as the answer so that people who search with a similar problem can see it.

Answer (score 0):

if the web services are all the same but the only difference between them is the path, you can create a service reference normally and in the constructor you assign the binding name and the new HTTP Uri, something like this

```
var serviceClient = new ServiceClient("http", txtUriPath.Text);
```

But if you have distinct methods for distinct Uri path of each Web Service, them you must let us know the error you actually have.